# sum of all columns in all sheets

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with multiple sheets like this:

sheet 1

```
column_A column_B
0         5
1         2
4         6
3         7
```

sheet 2

```
column_A column_B 
9         1        
5         2        
2         0        
4         7
```

and I want the sum of the columns in all sheets like this
Column A = 28
column B = 30

how to do it in pandas?

Comment: you can concatinate tha data of sheet all together then calculate sum

Comment: Can you share the code you already tried? Pandas can be a solution, but depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
sheets=[]
total_sheets=len(xls.sheet_names)
for i in range(total_sheets):
    sheets.append(xls.parse(i))

x=np.stack(sheets)
np.sum(x,axis=(0,1))
```